# Updating .po files without restarting lighty

Tags: php, gettext, lighttpd

We are running PHP with gettext on the lighttpd web server. When we update the .po/.mo files with new translations, we have to restart lighty for the new translations to appear.

Is lighty caching the translations?

Anyone know how to avoid restarting lighty?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, PHP's gettext extension is caching .mo files, so that's not only lighty's problem :)

I'd suggest using `Zend_Translate` component. `Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext` does not use the PHP gettext extension, but carries its own implementation. Besides, `Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext` is muti-thread safe, which is not true for PHP gettext extension.

Comment: Ahaa.... OK thanks for the tip! I also wonder if there's a way to disable the gettext extensions caching?

Comment: Anyway I solved the gettext caching by changing the filename of the .mo files each time I imported new translations... Would be better if there was a method to flush them :/